# Conditional using a string in Java after using Scanner

Tags: java

It always give the second conditional regardless of the input. Is (userName == "Charles") the correct way of doing this conditional? or do i need something else.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Name_input {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
           Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            String userName = input.next();
            System.out.println(userName);

            if (userName == "Charles")
            {
                System.out.println("Correct Name");
            }       
            else if (userName != "Charles")
            {
                System.out.println("Incorrect Name");
            }       
      }

}
```

Comment: You can't compare equality of Strings using `==` use `.equals()` instead.

Answer (score -2):

> Is (userName == "Charles") the correct way of doing this conditional

No You don't use "==" to compare strings.

Instead you should be using the `equals(...)` method:

```
if ( "Charles".equals( userName ) )
```

Note I reversed the order of the comparison. This will prevent a NPE if the username is ever null.

> System.out.println(userName);

Does that display the expected value? Do you need to use the trim() method?

```
else if (userName != "Charles")
```

Also, there is no need for the "else if". The name is either "Charles" or it isn't so you don't need the additional "if" statement.

Comment: Not sure why you got all the downvotes, I thought your answer was pretty swell.

Comment: @RobOhRob Probably people are DVing a very high-rep user answering an obvious dupe. More on principle than the quality of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, i really appreciate it.

Comment: @J.M.C.B, glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.